# Powershell accepting multiple parameters for switch statement from user input

Tags: powershell, switch-statement, user-input

I am trying to find a way to accept user to invoke multiple switch statements for example

```
$order = Read-Host "Place Order"

Switch ($order){
 1{echo "Burger"}
 2{echo "Fries"}
 3{echo "Drink"}
}
```

You can only type 1, 2, or 3 but if you wanted multiple you could put it into an array

```
$order = @('1','2')

Switch ($order){
 1{echo "Burger"}
 2{echo "Fries"}
 3{echo "Drink"}
}
```

> output:
>   Burger
>   Fries

But how do I get user input and format it into an array value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once simple solution is to ask the user to specify their order separated by commas:

```
$order = Read-Host "Place Order (use commas to separate items)"

Switch ($order.Split(',')){
 1{echo "Burger"}
 2{echo "Fries"}
 3{echo "Drink"}
}
```

So for this input:

`Place Order (use commas to separate items): 1,3`

I get this output:

```
Burger
Drink
```

This still works of they only specify a single item, or none at all - you probably need a default option for no input.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for thank you!